# userdata events in internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer

Are events fired when userdata is changed in ie, similar to how change events are fired on sessionStorage?  I was looking on msdn and could not find any mention of events. I am trying to notiy other open ie7 windows that some userdata has changed.

Answer (score 0):

The SAME event should fire whether it's session or local. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc197059%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a link to the MSDN page explaining the onStorage event.

Answer (score 0):

So far as I can tell, the userData has no such related event to trigger. But there is a workaround for it which I learned form [jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info). You can use `setTimeout` to check the userData status. More details about is [here](https://github.com/andris9/jStorage/blob/master/jstorage.js).